# extracting pixel value from a table in postgresql

Tags: postgis, postgresql, coordinate-system

I have a table in postgresql that contains ID, row number, column number, pixel value and centroid of the pixel in WGS84 lat-lon system(4326). How could I extract the pixel value by giving a point in 4326 reference system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT pixel_value FROM raster_table
WHERE ST_Intersects(ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(xcoord,ycoord), 4326),rast)=TRUE;
```

Then according to your new comments the SQL-command could be

```
SELECT pixel_value FROM your_table_with_pixels
WHERE ST_Intersects(ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(xcoord,ycoord), 4326),ST_Buffer(geom, resolution_of_raster_cell))=TRUE;
```

Comment: Thank you Vladimir, but maybe my question was not clear enough. I'm not working on _postgis raster_. This is just a set of pixels of a raster file with row number, column number, pixel values and pixel centroid in 4326.

Comment: The pixels have to have coordinates, otherwise it is impossible to extract values. Where are the coordinates of pixels stored?

Comment: the coordinates of centroid of pixels are available.

Comment: What is their representation? As geometry PostGIS data type? WKT? WKB?

Comment: yes, geometry type WKT

Comment: I have also row number and column number in image coordinate system. Is it possible for the user to give row_number and column_number and the query do some sort of transformation to geometry coordinate system and extract values?